# How to force fsck on reboot for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, fsck

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an embedded device. I will like to ask how to force automatic fsck on bootup? In older Ubuntu versions, this can be achieved by editing the /etc/default/rcS and setting FSCKFIX=yes. However, I read that in newer Ubuntu, this file is not used anymore. So what will be the way to enable automatic fsck on bootup for newer Ubuntu?

Comment: @guiverc question is about how to initiate a fsck during boot, like we could in earlier days using `sudo touch /forcefsck`. To my consternation, I see today: `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p2 | grep checked` - `Last checked:             Sat Oct 31 13:03:57 2020`. Does that indicate that the system file system is not anymore automatically checked nowadays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to force fsck with each reboot, there are few steps you need to follow.

1. use `blkid` to identify the uuid for the partition.

```
amarcus@amarcus-desktop:~$ blkid
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: UUID="d24b0766-c9be-49ef-9022-8ccae4f79801" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: UUID="d414c4f9-da0d-42bf-8290-4bcb55b8d984" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
amarcus@amarcus-desktop:~$
```

2. Use uuid or mount point to locate the partition in `/etc/fstab`

```
amarcus@amarcus-desktop:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=0AE0-795B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=D41C-2F17 /mnt/WDElements auto umask=0022,gid=1000,uid=1000,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

The last column that is a column 6, aka fsck PASS column is used by fsck to determine whether fsck should check filesystem before it is mounted and in which order given partitions in /etc/fstab should be checked

For root partitions, make sure that entry is set to 1

3. Finally, set the mount counter for that partition to 1.

```
root@amarcus-desktop:~# tune2fs -c 1 /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
```

Explanation:

Basically, in step 1 you are identifying which partition you want to check at boot.

In step 2, you are making sure that it takes higher priory. It's useful if you are checking more than one partitions. It decide which should be taken up first, then second and so on.

In step 3, you are saying after how many mounts the partition should be checked. The argument 1 specifies that after one mount the partition should be checked. So basically it checks after each mount, i.e. after every restart.

Comment: @vanadium you are right. I just checked in my new 21.04 system and sudo touch /forcefsck is not working.  Good news is that tune2fs -c 1 /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root works. It checks file system after each reboot in my ubuntu 21.04

Comment: @vanadium - about your message on 

```sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p2 | grep checked```

In your fstab when root partition is 1 in last column does not mean that it will check the partition after 1 mount. That number in fstab is the priority in which  the partition should be checked. Making sure it is 1 for root partition means whenever file system is checked, root partition will be checked "first".

In my answer - in step 3,  when you run ```tune2fs -c 1 /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root``` that is where you are specifying file system check after each 1 mount.


Hope this helps

Comment: @vanadium If you are not sure you just try it and post the right answer as nobody wants to know your doubts. Good thing is testing this takes no more than couple of minutes. Bad thing is now your doubts are read forever by infinite number of people.

Comment: @midenok I posted an answer halve an hour later (see above), so I did follow your advise.

Comment: @midenok Also note that comments are only intended to improve on a question or post, and thus are temporary. They actually may disappear any time - I deleted mine here, and I would suggest you delete your comment as well.

Comment: You cannot use -c 1 now. Use -c 2 and reboot two times.

Answer (score 21):

The old convenient trick of creating a file `/forcefsck` to force a file check on reboot does not work anymore since `systemd` took over initialisation.

**Change "Maximum number of mounts" (only ext file systems)**

The quickest way, probably, is to temporarily change your `Maximum mount count` to `1`. That will cause the kernel and `e2fsck` to check the file system on the next reboot. However, this only works with ext file systems.

First check your current setting in case you want to restore to default later:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p2 | grep 'Maximum mount'
```

Substitute `/dev/nvme0n1p2` by the device name of your system partition. Chances are this is set to `-1` nowadays, disabling check based on the number of times the volume has been mounted.

Adjust the setting to `1` with the command:

```
sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

Now reboot - the volume should be checked. After reboot, you should reset the value to what it was before in order to avoid the partition being checked everytime.

**Change kernel parameter**

Another way is to [pass kernel parameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) during boot that control the [systemd services for file system check](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html). `fsck.mode=force` will force a file check.

To add a kernel parameter for a single time, boot to the Grub menu, highlight the entry and hit <kbd>e</kbd>. Move to the line starting with `linux`, hit <kbd>End</kbd> to move to the last line, add a space and the kernel parameter. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to close and continue booting.

Comment: `fsck.mode=force` is the best solution, and the most similar to the `/forcefsck` old behavior. The best would be to create a new dedicated GRUB entry for that IMHO. (+1)

Comment: Why do you say grub entry is better than the other option?

Comment: @Freedo I am not saying that as far as I see. I am providing two options, one specifically for ext4 (there may be similar options for e.g. btrfs or not), and the grub way, which does not depend on the specific file system.

Comment: Might seem obvious to some but will using this solution will fsck auto repair errors or just wait for user to enter a 'y' in case of errors ? I would like to autofix to make sure I can still access it remotely if this happens.

Comment: -c 1 is "invalid" and modern tune2fs 1.47.0 complains about it. LOL. Just set it to 2 and reboot two times.

Answer (score 3):

Up to 20.04 under root privileges:

```
touch /forcefsck
reboot
```

You don't have to remove `/forcefsck` as the system removes it.

After 20.04 (thanks to systemd which never makes your life easier):

Add fsck.mode=force and fsck.repair=yes to kernel boot parameter either as new grub menu item or by editing kernel string at booting.

Comment: Another answer states that it doesn't work anymore: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352774/how-to-force-fsck-on-reboot-for-ubuntu-20-04/1352782#1352782

Comment: I don't tell anything that didn't work for me. That would be stupid: push dead information back and forth. @a-l Did you check that it doesn't work or you just push information back and forth?

Comment: yup, doesn't work anymore on ubuntu (ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS). No need to call anyone stupid.

Comment: Can confirm that it works on Ubuntu 20.04. And it's a much simpler solution than the nightmare of confusion mentioned in the accepted answer.that said, maybe it won't work when I upgrade to 22.04. there should be some simple way to do this though!

Comment: @midenok I think this solution is valuable since it's so much simpler, but maybe you should consider adding that it only works for ubuntu <20.04