# How to solve dpkg error based on geany-plugin-addons

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg, geany

Error that I got from the upgrading step:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 loading files list file for package 'geany-plugin-addons': cannot read /var/lib/dpkg/info/geany-plugin-addons.list (Input/output error)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I also ran this command.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get full-upgrade
```

but it didn't work for me. The above error showed over and over again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/install a package that is not fully installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed)

Comment: That file is suffering from filesystem corruption, so let's remove it with https://askubuntu.com/a/920304/1004020 . You then want to check your filesystem with https://askubuntu.com/a/1352782/1004020